# How to undo delete from Room database

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to implement the undo delete on a snackbar when a recycler item is swiped by caching the item before it is deleted and if undo is clicked, item should be added to recyclerview from cache.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Here's my current code

```java
@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).get(ViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getAllAppointments().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Appointments>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Appointments> appointments) {
            mAdapter.submitList(appointments);
        }
    });

    Snackbar.make(Objects.requireNonNull(getView()), "Appointment deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //undo delete
                }
            })
            .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
            .addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback(){
                @Override
                public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                    super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);

                    if (event == DISMISS_EVENT_TIMEOUT || event == DISMISS_EVENT_SWIPE
                            || event == DISMISS_EVENT_CONSECUTIVE || event == DISMISS_EVENT_MANUAL) {
                        viewModel.delete(mAdapter.getAppointAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                    }
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For doing this work you can call show snackbar in onClick button, so when finish time snackbar invoke delete function (delete from adapter, list, and database or data source), so before this time use can remove item just from adapter temporally for only animat similar  (not remove from list) and if user clicked on undo button doing refresh list from database or your data source

Comment: Thanks. I never thought to do it like that, I'll try it

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?